# How do i make my private URL as Public?

Tags: url, web, qliksense

I have one URL which is generated through **qliksenseserver**,,
Format is : https:///extensions.....
But this url is only accessible to that server,,i need to make this url available to my **webserver** [just to make as public]

Answer (score 0):

Can you pls elaborate a bit more what you are trying to achieve and what's not working as expected. Unfortunately do not fully understand the challenge you are describing.